# mongodb create database with dot/dash symbols

Tags: mongodb

I need to create database named "my-database" (yes, with "-" or "." sym). I tried default syntax to achive that (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/):

```
1) use my-database
2) db['test'].insert( {'foo':'bar'} )
3) show dbs // oh, God! I have done it!
```

But after first line I get

```
Error: Line 1: Unexpected identifier
```

How can I create database with name "my.db" / "my-db" via mongo shell?

UPDATE: this error occurs if I try to use commands from list above in Robomongo console... In mongo shell all works well.

```
> use test-db
switched to db test-db
> db['test-collection'].insert( {'foo':'bar'} );
> db['test-collection'].find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f36049812d284697e80ffd"), "foo" : "bar" }
```

It's because Robomongo doesn't use the same V8 engine that mongo uses - it uses Spidermonkey. (thanks Lix)

Comment: Hmmm.. this seems to work for me using MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6. Can you please share with us what version of mongo you are using?

Comment: "version" : "2.2.3" . Usually, I am using Robomongo for create db/collection operations. Now, I already have many databases with names "prefix-dbname" / "prefix.dbname" . But if I try to create another like that manually - I get error. mystic?

Comment: Hmm.. I've had issues in the past using Robomongo stemming from the fact that Robomongo doesn't use the same V8 engine that mongo uses - it uses Spidermonkey. Perhaps this is the issue. Can you try execute those commands directly on the mongo shell?

Comment: (* I know I know... Robomongo is quite awesome :P - I wish it worked just as well as the official shell *)

Comment: Thanks! I did not take into account the fact what I am in robomongo environment... )

Comment: No problem :) Beware of using `ISODate()` with robomongo also... it doesn't like it :P

Comment: The V8 engine is used as of version 2.4.

Comment: Note also that you can't (or at least shouldn't) be able to make databases with .'s in the names. .'s are fine in collection names (`db.system.indexes`, for example) but no .'s are allowed in the database name so the namespace `<database>.<collection>` can always be resolved into its components unambiguously.

Comment: This issue persists with robo 3T 1.3.1